# How to fix this issue with running integration testing in Flutter?

Tags: git, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

When trying to do integration testing with this command

`lutter drive --target=my_app/test_driver/my_test.dart`

I always get this error:

```
       The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly;
       to set up Flutter, run the following command:
       git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

When I follow what they said by running `git clone -b stable https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git` I always recieve this:

```
fatal: destination path 'flutter' already exists and is not an empty directory.
macpros-MBP:flutter_app CompteEtudiant$
```

Comment: what do you get if you run flutter doctor ?

Comment: what does your `my_test.dart` file contain ?.  Usually the command is like this:  `flutter drive --target = test_driver/app.dart` when you run from your project root path and  `app.dart` is the file which contains the code to enable Flutter driver extension.